# 3d user experience with HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, javascript-framework

I've to build a 3D user experience with HTML5 and any required JS library which provides such functionality. 3D scene consists of a cylindrical pipe and surface. It has 360 degree rotation and can zoom in and out. As user selects a parameter, specific value of that parameter at various depth of pipe in surface should display.

I've searched for HTML5 3d and JS libraries and found three.js could help for this.Also found this useful presentation on HTML 3d engine: http://projects.mariusgundersen.net/OnGameStart/#1  .But as this is my first time with HTML5 3d modeling, how should I initiate to build ? What parameters should be considered ? Which tools and libraries would best fit for such requirements ?

[image: I would like to create a 3d model using HTML5 and JS 3d engine as shown in the 1st image.]

I would like to create a 3d model using HTML5 and JS 3d engine as shown in the 1st image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a similar little 3D animation using [blender](http://www.blender.org/) for the modeling, [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) as the JavaScript 3D engine and [tween.js](https://github.com/sole/tween.js/) for animation. You can [export models from blender to three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender).

Comment: Thank you maenu. This is a very good idea. Please let me know any other way to implement using HTML5 and JS 3d engine. I would like to  create a demo using HTML5 and JS 3d engine as the 3d image shown in this link [link](http://www.aogr.com/index.php/magazine/cover-story/opening-new-possibilities-for-oil-and-gas-operations).

Comment: Anybody please reply with other ways to implement this using HTML5 and JS 3d engine.